# Python: automatic data imputing based on machine learning

Tags: python, imputation

Besides filling the missing data with mean, one could actually use machine learning (even regression) to fill in the missing value. As there are more and more automatic machine learning code available. I wonder if there is any python code that allows me the fill in the missing value of pandas dataframe with some kind of machine learning method. Thanks.

Comment: That's a good thing to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the package called fancy impute.

https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancyimpute